# How to deploy a Java Japplet in iWeb developed on my Macbook?

Tags: macos, applet, iweb

I am building a website using iWeb on my Mac (latest versions of everything)
I am using the Html Snippet Widget to embed the applet tag.

Since iWeb does not seem to have any specific support for Java applets, my plan was to just publish the tag and then send over the required Jar file afterward.

However I can't get past the "apply" - because after I press apply, iWeb just hangs indefinitely.

Here is the tag...

<applet code="myApplet.class" codebase="java/" width="1000" height="700"  archive="myArchive.jar"
  <parameter name="example" value="morestuff">
  <parameter name="title" value="some text">
</applet>

I am seeing some interesting messages in the console about MalformedUrLException - unsupported protocol iweb-widget

Has anyone had any luck deploying applets using iWeb?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to put applets generated from my (very noob) "Processing" code into an iWeb site on MobileMe.

The Processing environment produces the `.jar` file and some applet tag in an `index.htm` file. In iWeb, I copied the applet tag stuff from the `index.htm` file and pasted it into the HTML Snippet widget.

The problem was where to put the `.jar` file. Putting it anywhere in the MobileMe storage space didn't work, no matter what I typed into the applet tag, so I dropped it into a dropbox (dropbox.com, free), copied the public link from the dropbox and replaced all instances of 'filename.jar' in the html in the snippet widget with the public link to the file in my dropbox.

Probably a proper shoddy way to do it, but it works.

It's [here](http://www.minepowercosmic.com/Hello_World!/How_Kevin_Darke_went_about_Learning_Processing/Entries/2011/5/14_llamas_are_bigger_than_frogs.html), if it helps...

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to StackOverflow! In the future it's best to leave out shortened url links within your answers, and instead link directly to the page.